# python - auditing lines from a file

Tags: python, file, lines, audit

I am trying to audit a file and store the results for each section, here is the file sample:

```
-------------- Task 1 -------------- Device Name: hostname_A
Status: Completed
Results: Action completed successfully...

****** Enable Mode Results ******
hostname_A#show run | in abcd
abcd RO 1
hostname_A#show ip access-list 1
Standard IP access list 1
    10 permit 1.1.1.1
    20 permit 2.2.2.2
    30 permit 3.3.3.3

-------------- Task 2 -------------- Device Name: hostname_B
Status: Completed
Results: Action completed successfully...

****** Enable Mode Results ******
hostname_A#show run | in abcd
hostname_A#show ip access-list 1
Standard IP access list 1
     10 permit 1.1.1.1
     20 permit 2.2.2.2

-------------- Task 3-------------- Device Name: hostname_C
And so on
```

And here is the Code I´ve created so far, but struggling to get it working:

```
with open("file_to_be_audited.txt", "r") as infile:
    with open ('audited_file.txt', "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if '--- Task' in line:           #setting a line/section delimiter
                for each_line_in_Task_Block: #trying to check/audit each line of that section
                        device_dict = {}
                        device_dict['hostname'] = re.search("Device Name: (.+)", each_line_in_Task_Block) # trying to store the DeviceName
                        if 'abcd' in line:
                            device_dict['community'] = 'Passed'
                        else:
                            device_dict['community'] = 'Failed'

                        if '2.2.2.2' and '3.3.3.3' in each_line_in_Task_Block:
                            device_dict['ACL'] = 'Passed'
                        else:
                            device_dict['ACL'] = 'Failed'

                    field_order = ('hostname', 'community', 'ACL')
                    for i in field_order:
                        outfile.write(device_dict[i])
```

The results would be something like:

```
hostname_A, community=Passed, ACL=Passed; 
hostname_B, community=Failed, ACL=Failed; 
hostname_C, community=Passed, ACL=Failed;
and so on
```

There are a lot of '--- Task ---' sections, the idea is to check and store the results of each 'Device Name' in another file. I am trying to get a better and working way of doing it. Any suggestion ? Thank you !

Comment: `if '2.2.2.2' and '3.3.3.3' in each_line_in_Task_Block` This is not how boolean logic works. this is interpretted as `if (('2.2.2.2') and ('3.3.3.3' in each_line_in_Task_Block))`. If that doesn't make sense then you need to read up on operator precedence and, specificallly, look at the python reference for the `in` statement. Your `for each_line...` is also incorrect. I think you need to go through a Python tutorial and get your basics down.

Comment: Thank you @RobertB, that (each_line_in_Task_Block) is just a way to demontrating what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Give an example of the output file you want.

Comment: something like:
hostname_A, community=Passed, ACL=Passed;
hostname_B, community=Failed, ACL=Failed;
hostname_C, community=Passed, ACL=Failed;

Comment: Please don't put the expected output in the comments, edit your question.

Comment: Without totally re-writing your code, I'm having a hard time coming up with specific advice. What you have posted is "psuedo-code" at best. I would advise to only have a single loop. With every line, try to recognize the type of line and determine what action should be taken. Don't do nested loops. E.g. This line contains '--- Task' so I should finish up any processing for the previous task and start a new task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted something more like this:

```
line = infile.readline()
while '--- Task' not in line: #find the first task (assuming it's not always the first line, ie some random '\n' lines in the beginning
    line = infile.readline()

deviceDict = {}
#parse the first line however you want
field_order = ('hostname', 'community', 'ACL')
#now you can jump into the for loop
for line in infile:
    taskblock = ''
    try: #keep while loop in a try block, explained below
        while '--- Task' not in line:
             taskblock = taskblock + line
             line = next(infile)

    #you can now parse taskblock as a string any way you want

    for i in field_order: #this is where you output, assuming you parsed aboved
            outfile.write(i + ' = ' + deviceDict[i])
            outfile.write(',' if i != 'ACL' else ';\n') #'ACL' can be changed to whatever your last element is
    deviceDict = {}
    if '--- Task' in line: #this is necessary because if next(infile) is called in the end of file, line == whatever the last line was since there are no more tasks
        #this is where you can parse the task line again (use the same code as before)
```

This is a framework for you to work with (lots of pseudocode). The comments are places where you can put specific code in. what the `while` loop does is keep adding lines to taskblock until it reaches the next task line. because file objects are iterators, we can call `next(infile)` on it to get the next line and iterate. We need that while loop inside of a `try` block because if `next(f)` is called at the end of file, it will raise a `StopIteration` error. you can also do something like:

```
for line in infile:
    taskblock = ''
        while '--- Task' not in line and line:
             taskblock = taskblock + line
             line = infile.readline()
```

which checks if `infile.readline()` was valid (it will return empty if it hits the end of line) but if any other line in your txt file is empty then this may cause problems.

as for your `if '2.2.2.2' and '3.3.3.3' in each_line_in_Task_Block:` line that, as it said in the comments, would not return what you would expect, you can use

```
if all(permit in taskblock for permit in ['2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3']):
```

to achieve the same effect.

I hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thank you @R Nar! I am trying using the code you suggested, but not getting through it, I might not be doing it correct, I am not a Python expert. Will keep trying it, let you know if get any luck. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

device_dict = {}

with open("file_to_be_audited.txt", "r") as infile:
  with open ('audited_file.txt', "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if "Device Name" in line:
            device_dict['hostname'] = re.search(r'Device Name: (.+)', line).group(0)
            outfile.write("\n") 
            outfile.write(device_dict['hostname'] + "\n") 
            #tried to have a cleaner code storing the dictionaries values and saving it all once at the end to the file, but didn´t get it working and as a solution, saving it at each item

        if "abcd RO 1" in line:
            device_dict['community'] = 'Passed'
            outfile.write('Community: ' + device_dict['community'] + "\n")
            # the same for all the other dicitonaries items, saving it at each time instead of the endb of the code

        if "Standard IP access list 1" in line:
            acl_lines = ' '
            while True:
                line = next(infile)
                acl_lines = acl_lines + line 
                if 'permit' not in line:
                    break
            if all (permit in acl_lines for permit in ['2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']):
                device_dict['ACL'] = 'Passed'
                outfile.write('ACL 1    : ' + device_dict['ACL'] + "\n")    
            else:
                device_dict['ACL'] = 'Failed'
                outfile.write('ACL 1    : ' + device_dict['ACL'] + "\n")
```

And here is the outfile from this code:

```
Device Name: hostname_A
Community: Passed
ACL 1    : Passed

Device Name: hostname_B
ACL 1    : Failed
```

Comment: Following RobertB and R Nar suggestions/comments/advices/code, have now rebuilt the code lines, that is accomplishing what I was looking for.